# Can I delete a folder named 6050a66d813ea943d4?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

It is on the c drive root and there are no normal or hidden files in it. Would it be okay if iIdeleted it?

Comment: Could be a software you have uses it. If that's the case and you delete it, it'll probably just be created again by that software, but just in case, I'd suggest to leave it alone unless you know it's useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These types of files are usually remnants of installations. Commonly Windows Updates. It's actually good house keeping to remove these folders if they are there.

Comment: I will delete it then. I hate how windows creates so many folders for no reason. Thanks.

Comment: It's no trouble... in my last job I would constantly find our servers riddled with these types of folders. I deleted without prejudice many times and didn't experience consequences.

Comment: @Brandon it has a perfectly good reason, those folders are created by a msi file during a install, it chooses the largest local drive with the most free space to extract it's files. If everything goes correctly the folder is deleted, however if the install process crashes or the computer was shut off before it completes the folders will be left behind.